# Iterate through rows and create text for summarization model?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, huggingface-transformers, summarization, spacy-transformers

I'm working with a dataframe that looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ETF3.png)

I want to be able to iterate through the rows and have a new column called C that looks like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOCQU.png)

I keep getting several of the same text about 2 times in each row instead of just one.

After that, I want to be able to run a summarization model from hugging face for each of the C values. For example

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fShrz.png)

Each row has a summarization, the pipeline only takes strings and instead it's telling me it's in the wrong format.

```
`args[0]`: 0    happyugly1    sadprettyName: C, dtype: object have the wrong format. The should be either of type `str` or type `list`
```

Comment: You are calling `test['C']` instead of `row['C']`, `test` is your DataFrame and returns a series object with the values of all the columns.

Comment: I figured out that to combine for the text in C, it is `df['C']= df[['A','B']].apply(lambda row: '.'.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)`